# SSH connection can be established but sftp connection is denied via terminal or any client

Tags: ssh, sftp

Here is my sshd_config

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 4422
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
Ciphers aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour
#KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
```

I do have root access and here is the result of

```
$ iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: Are you sure that you using port `4422` when you trying to connect to the server via sftp?

Comment: @pa4080  port 4422 is used for ssh connection and there is no configuration written for sftp connection ,do I need to write some rules ?
previously I can establish sftp connection but now I can't , though I haven't change any configuration .

Comment: No, you you do not need to write additional rules. My thought was that when you using sftp you should mention the custom port into the client's command, for example: `scp -P  4422 ...` or `sshfs -p4422 ..`.

Comment: sftp user@1.2.3.4
ssh: connect to host 1.2.3.4 port 22: Connection refused
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer

Comment: Exactly what I mean. You should use: `sftp -P 4422 user@1.2.3.4`.

Comment: ssh: connect to host 4422 port 22: Invalid argument


Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer

Comment: The problem is somewhere into your sftp command, probably missing `-P` argument. Here you are [an example screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TMAg.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because into your configuration has a custom ssh port - `4422`, you must provide it within the sftp command, for example:

```
sftp -P 4422 user@1.2.3.4
```